# Flutter static members can't reference type parameters of the class

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to create an abstract class with all the common functions so that code repetition is less. For e.g I have two model classes `TestModel` and `TestModel1` with the same functionality of adding, getting data to Firestore but with different attributes mainly `name` and `name1`.
Now i wanna do `TestModel.get()` to get all the data stored or `TestModel.add(data)` to add data. But the problem is `Static members can't reference type parameters of the class.`
Now is there any workaround to the problem or some better way to achieve what I'm trynna do. Please refer to below code for the details.

```
abstract class Database<T> {
  /// constants
  static final testModelName = 'TestModelName';
  static final testModelName1 = 'TestModelName1';

  /// constructor
  Database(String collectionName) {
    ref =
        FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection(collectionName).withConverter<T>(
              fromFirestore: (snapshot, _) => fromJson(snapshot.data()!),
              toFirestore: (t, _) => toJson(),
            );
  }

  static late final CollectionReference<T>
      ref; // Static members can't reference type parameters of the class.

  /// json serialization
  Map<String, dynamic> toJson();

  T fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json);

  /// helper function

  static Future<List<T>> get() async {
    // Static members can't reference type parameters of the class.
    return (await ref.get()).docs.map((e) => e.data()).toList();
  }

  static Future<void> add(T data) async {
    // Static members can't reference type parameters of the class.
    await ref.add(data);
  }
}

class TestModel extends Database<TestModel> {
  TestModel(this.id, this.name) : super(Database.testModelName);

  final String id;
  final String name;

  @override
  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        'id': id,
        'name': name,
      };

  @override
  TestModel fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) =>
      TestModel(json['id'], json['name']);
}

class TestModel1 extends Database<TestModel1> {
  TestModel1(this.id, this.name, this.name1) : super(Database.testModelName1);

  final String id;
  final String name;
  final String name1;

  @override
  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        'id': id,
        'name': name,
        'name1': name1,
      };

  @override
  TestModel1 fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) =>
      TestModel1(json['id'], json['name'], json['name1']);
}
```

Comment: Your `Database` constructor assigns the `static` `ref` member, so how is that supposed to work if there are multiple `Database` instances?  Is your intention for there to be a single `Database` instance per `T`?

Comment: The ref and other functions are common to all `TestModel`. The only difference is the `ref` name and the `TestModel` Type because different `TestModel` can have different attributes. But I want to write all logic only once so that I won't have to repeat it in every class. Isn't there any way to do that? Because my current implementation is wrong I guess.

Comment: So what's supposed to happen if you construct multiple `TestModel` objects?  Is `ref` supposed to be replaced by the latest `TestModel` instance?  Is the first `ref` supposed to be the winner?  A single `ref` for all `TestModel`s makes sense only if `TestModel` is a singleton (and similarly for all other classes that derive from `Database`).

Comment: `TestModel` should be singleton only, but I'm not getting any idea on how to make all `TestModel` classes singleton without repeating the code for singleton classes for all the TestModel classes.

Comment: I want `static get` and `static add` methods in the `TestModel` and `TestModel1` classes. And there can be many `TestModel` classes but all will have the same implementation of `get()` and `add()`. So I wanted to write it once in the abstract class only, but I guess it will not work. I wanted to call get and add like `TestModel.get()` or `TestModel1.add(data)`

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you want something like:

```dart
class Foo<T> {
  // ERROR: Static members can't reference type parameters of the class.
  static final allFoosOfExactType = <T>[];
  
  Foo() {
    allFoosOfExactType.add(this);
  }
}
```

A workaround could be to use a `Map<Type, ...>` with generic global functions to access it:

```dart
class Foo<T> {
  Foo() {
    getAllFoosOfExactType<T>().add(this);
  }
}

final _allFoosMap = <Type, List<Foo<Object?>>>{};

List<Foo<T>> getAllFoosOfExactType<T>() {
  assert(T != dynamic);
  return (_allFoosMap[T] ??= <Foo<T>>[]) as List<Foo<T>>;
}
```

Normally using `Map<Type, ...>` isn't a great idea because lookups require an exact match and would not work for derived types, but that does not seem like a concern for your expected usage.

In your case, you therefore maybe could do:

```dart
Future<List<T>> get<T>() async {
  return (await getRef<T>().get()).docs.map((e) => e.data()).toList();
}

Future<void> add<T>(T data) async {
  await getRef<T>().add(data);
}

final _allRefs = <Type, CollectionReference<Object?>>{};

void setRef<T>(CollectionReference<T> ref) {
  assert(!_allRefs.containsKey(T), 'setRef<$T> already called');
  _allRefs[T] = ref;
}

CollectionReference<T> getRef<T>() {
  assert(T != dynamic);
  return _allRefs[T]! as CollectionReference<T>;
}

abstract class Database<T> {
  /// constants
  static final testModelName = 'TestModelName';
  static final testModelName1 = 'TestModelName1';

  /// constructor
  Database(String collectionName) {
    setRef(CollectionReference<T>());
  }

  /// json serialization
  Map<String, dynamic> toJson();

  T fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json);
}
```